Mover registros de un campo a otro campo en MYSQL
Buen día.
Tengo una duda, realice un join en MYSQL y tengo 2 registros que quiero que se pasen a otro campo para así eliminar el campo que no necesito. ¿Existe alguna forma de mover los registros (geom1) del id 5049 y 5576 al campo (geom)?

NOTA: Pero en una misma tabla ya que hice el join y me jalo por separado ambos geoms.



as intentando un UPDATE T1
SET T1.geom1= T2.geom
FROM Table1 T1
JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE T1.ID in (5049,5576)

en mysql es:
UPDATE {tabla1} t1
/* JOIN EN CASO QUE SEA REQUERIDO */
JOIN {tabla2} t2
ON t1.{id} = t2.{t1_id}
/* */
SET t1.{geom} = t2.{geom1}
WHERE t1.{id} IN (5049,5576)


que hacen las llaves?
